# Delete spreadsheet data by using google scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i'm trying to delete a specific row in google spreadsheet by using google scripts. I have created separate html page in order to inter the row id.But when I run the program I'm getting this error.

{"result":"error","error":{"message":"Cannot find method deleteRow((class)).","name":"InternalError","fileName":"Code","lineNumber":52,"stack":"\tat Code:52 (handleResponse)\n\tat Code:18 (doGet)\n"}}

[Here is my source code and I have created java script file in the same folder and external html file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eU0ve.jpg)
References- https://mashe.hawksey.info/2014/07/google-sheets-as-a-database-insert-with-apps-script-using-postget-methods-with-ajax-example/

Answer (score 0):

This will delete a row.

```
function drow()
{
  var sht=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var response = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt('Delete Row', 'Enter Row Number to Delete', SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);
  var rownum = Number(response.getResponseText());
  sht.deleteRow(rownum);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, it works fine. But I need to delete it through the html webpage. Rather than running the script in script editor. Is there any way that i can do it through html webpage.?

Comment: [HTML Service: Communicate with Server Functions google.script.run is an asynchronous client-side JavaScript API that allows HTML-service pages to call server-side Apps Script functions.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)